# jQuery - click (almost!) anywhere to hide div etc

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".clickPlan").click(function(){
  $(".panel1").animate({left:'0px'});
});  
$(".sendBtn").click(function(){
  $(".panel1").animate({left:'300px'});
});  
$(document).click(function() { 
  $('.panelBox').fadeOut('fast'); 
});
$(".clickPlan").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/stupaul22/qV246/5/

I am close. This is the functionality I want.

Click "SHOW PANEL" animates the panel onto the screen.
You can enter name and email without making the panel disappear.
Clicking "SEND" animates the panel off to the right.
Clicking anywhere outside the panel and outside "SHOW PANEL" makes the panel fade.

After a fade -->  Click "SHOW PANEL" animates the panel onto the screen FROM LEFT.

Comment: I don't think your fiddle is working properly ?

Comment: Your current code is hiding the `.clickPlan` element so you can't click it in the first place. You might want to re-arrange your elements so that the element which will show the form is on the out-most right part and clearly visible. Ones you have your code in a current working state it will be easier to help you out with the rest of the details.

Comment: Ok here's the working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/stupaul22/qV246/5/

Comment: Rather than just "I am close" could you please be clearer in your question about which part of your desired functionality doesn't work yet? (If it's the "from left" part, surely you just have to set the `left` position back to the original negative x coordinate after fading, and call `.show()` just before `.animate()`?)

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a click handler to the `.panel1` class and stop the event from propagating to the click handler that's on your document.

```
// will stop the event from reaching the $(document).click handler
$(".panel1").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qV246/6/

Comment: Below is the code I'm using now. The panels do not disappear properly when you click inside the #container <div>. This is the container that holds the pie chart. Why is:
`         $(document).click(function() ` disabled inside that div?
` http://vitree.com/static/result.html`

Comment: the script code is in the fiddle, but please look at ` vitree.com/static/result.html `to see the proble in action.
@Brett